# Preventing someone from refreshing the page while uploading the form and image?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which you can upload text data to a database and an image in the same form. Everything works well. I use jQuery AJAX with PHP to submit the form.

It submits well with the image if attached but the problem is that when I show the loader while uploading, the user still has the ability to refresh the page from the browser which sometimes uploads only the text and not the attached image which shows the post without an image. How can I prevent this from happening?

I did not share any codes for now because I did not know which way to go asking this question

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent a from from re-submitting?

Comment: You can put a message on the screen (because everyone *always* reads warning messages) asking the user very nicely not to reload the page... realistically though, there's not much you can do to prevent someone mashing F5 (short of using a nailgun to staple their hands to the desk maybe).

Comment: then how can i prevent the text data from uploading if the picture is not uploaded yet ? should i do it using the php script?

Comment: Are you making two separate AJAX requests - one for the text and one for the image?

Comment: You can't prevent it from uploading but you _could_ check `$_FILES['tmpname']['error']` to see if there was a problem with the file upload, and if so abort (so nothing is saved) and send a notification back to the client.

Comment: no it is one ajax request but 2 options, if the user has attached a picture then an ajax request will fire and upload picture and text with 1 php script but if the user did not attach an image and only text then an ajax request will fire and upload the text data using php script

Comment: @CD001 you are suggesting that i check if the file has been uploaded successfully, if so then insert text data into database ?

Comment: @jwright91 - yeah, that'll get the result you're after as I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can show warning to user by using below method:

```
function enableBeforeUnload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        return true;
    };
}
function disableBeforeUnload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}

if(processing)
   enableBeforeUnload();
else
  disableBeforeUnload();
```

**Note:** This will just take user's confirmation before leaving which will let user think what he is going to do! You can't prevent him doing that.

Comment: will this popup a window and ask are you sure you want to close the window ?

Comment: ok can you please explain what is the variable processing ? what should go in the if() in place of processing ?